# do not add `name` key value when generating docker compose file using `docker compose config` command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There seems to be a discrepancy in the implementation between `docker compose` CLI command and `docker-compose` CLI. Although they follow the same specification for Compose.

### Services

As a simple example, I have two compose files

#### `docker-compose.hello-world.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  hello:
    image: hello-world:nano-server
    container_name: hello_world
```

#### `docker-compose.base.yml`

very simple base file

```yaml
version: '3.7'
volumes:
  dummy-vol:
```

I can override them using the `-f` flag as follows:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.hello-world.yml -f docker-compose.base.yml config > docker-compose.yml
```

### Discrepancy

If one uses the above command using the `docker compose` CLI in built in the Docker Engine:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.hello-world.yml -f docker-compose.base.yml config
```

The resultant configuration generated is:

here `test-con` is just the name of the directory I have the files in

```yaml
name: test-con
services:
  hello:
    container_name: hello_world
    image: hello-world:nano-server
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: test-con_default
```

However when using the `docker-compose` CLI,

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.hello-world.yml -f docker-compose.base.yml config
```

generates the following output:

```yaml
services:
  hello:
    container_name: hello_world
    image: hello-world:nano-server
version: '3.7'
volumes:
  test: {}
```

As you can see `name` key value is not generated with `docker-compose`.

Is there a way to suppress generating the `name` key-value from `docker compose` CLI?

### System Specs

`docker version`

```sh
Client:
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.5
 Git commit:        e91ed5707e
 Built:             Mon Dec 13 22:31:40 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.5
  Git commit:       459d0dfbbb
  Built:            Mon Dec 13 22:30:43 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.1
  GitCommit:        10f428dac7cec44c864e1b830a4623af27a9fc70.m
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.0
  GitCommit:        v1.1.0-0-g067aaf85
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

`docker compose version`

```sh
Docker Compose version 2.3.3
```

`docker-compose version`

```sh
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.10.2
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
```

Comment: It looks like `docker compose config` is generating Compose files that use the [Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-top-level-element), which the previous (and extremely widespread) `docker-compose` tool doesn't support.  Also note the missing `version:` element, which `docker-compose` interprets as meaning "Compose file version 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discrepancy is resolved when upgraded to `v2.4.1` for docker.

Upon conducting the same test:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.hello-world.yml config > std.yml
```

as well as

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.hello-world.yml config > cli.yml
```

and checking to see if there is any difference using  `diff`

```sh
diff std.yml cli.yml
```

now provides the same configuration in both tools

```yaml
name: test-com
services:
  hello:
    container_name: hello_world
    image: hello-world:nano-server
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: test-com_default
```